# How to extract the useful data with regular expression in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

Sorry guys, it seems like I didn't explain my question clearly. Please allow me to rephrase my question again.

1. I use WebClient to download the whole webpage and I got the content as a string

   "

   .......


   .....
   var picArr ="/d/manhua/naruto/516/1.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/2.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/3.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/4.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/5.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/6.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/7.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/8.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/9.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/10.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/11.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/12.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/13.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/14.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/15.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/16.png"
   ......
   ";

in this content, I want to get only one line which is

```
var picArr ="/d/manhua/naruto/516/1.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/2.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/3.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/4.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/5.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/6.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/7.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/8.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/9.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/10.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/11.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/12.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/13.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/14.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/15.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/16.png"
```

now I want use regular expression to get this string and get the value of picArr.

my reg exp is
var picArr ="([.]*)"

I think the dot means any characters. But it doesn't work. :(

Any idea?

THanks a lot

Comment: "The value of picArr"? The *value* is exactly as you defined it, there's nothing to "extract". Do you mean you want the file names? The `.` does mean any character (except newline), but only when it's not in a character class. And searching for `.*` will just return the string itself, which is pretty pointless. Have you given this any thought?

Comment: @Mark, Hi mark thanks to make my question beautiful :), I don't get your point.  My question is this picArr is on the webpage, it's not mine variable. So after I retrieved the content of this page, there is one line like this that I want to get.

Comment: Franva: Oh... that whole thing, `"var picArr = ..." is somewhere in the source code? I thought that was your code. In that case.... there are a billion ways to do it. Does the `"/dmanhua"` part ever change? Does the `var` part ever change? Without more context, we don't know how much or how "exact" the expression needs to be.

Comment: Just to add to the information: You can use the free tool Expreso (http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) to create regular expressions as well as test them. It can also generate the c# or vb.net code to implement the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ExtractFileNames
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pageData = @"blah blah
var picArr =""/d/manhua/naruto/516/1.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/2.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/3.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/4.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/5.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/6.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/7.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/8.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/9.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/10.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/11.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/12.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/13.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/14.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/15.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/16.png""
more blah decimal blah";

            var match = Regex.Match(pageData, @"var\s+picArr\s*=\s*""(.*?)""");
            var str = match.Groups[1].Value;
            var files = str.Split('|');
            foreach(var f in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(f);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/d/manhua/naruto/516/1.png
/d/manhua/naruto/516/2.png
/d/manhua/naruto/516/3.png
/d/manhua/naruto/516/4.png
/d/manhua/naruto/516/5.png
/d/manhua/naruto/516/6.png
/d/manhua/naruto/516/7.png
/d/manhua/naruto/516/8.png
/d/manhua/naruto/516/9.png
/d/manhua/naruto/516/10.png
/d/manhua/naruto/516/11.png
/d/manhua/naruto/516/12.png
/d/manhua/naruto/516/13.png
/d/manhua/naruto/516/14.png
/d/manhua/naruto/516/15.png
/d/manhua/naruto/516/16.png
```

Comment: Thanks Mark,  your code works perfectly for me ^_^  I highly appreciate your code and your time ^_^

Comment: one more question. Could you please explain your regular expression for me? thanks why you used double "" and why inside the brackets you used .*?   what are the meanings of them?

Comment: @Franva:Double quotes are converted to single quotes in an @-quoted string. It also prevents any escape chars, so they're quite handy for regexes. The `?` makes the `.*` bit non-greedy. By default `.*` will consume as many characters as possible, if you put `?` after it will consume as few as possible. Without the `?` if you had another quote anywhere in that string, it would eat up until the very last quote it could find and give you the wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
/picArr =\"([^\"]+)\"/
```

If I got this right that's what you need.

Comment: You wouldn't put the `/` at the start and end in C# though.. And since you're not actually defining this in code, but giving us a straight up regex, you don't really need to escape the quotes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advices, I didn't put a space after the "=" because the target string doesn't have any.

Comment: Just noticed. My bad ;) I +1'd you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the filenames, you could just do a split on the pipe:

```
        var picArr = "/d/manhua/naruto/516/1.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/2.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/3.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/4.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/5.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/6.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/7.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/8.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/9.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/10.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/11.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/12.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/13.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/14.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/15.png|/d/manhua/naruto/516/16.png";

        var splitPics = picArr.Split('|');

        foreach (var pic in splitPics)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pic);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the value of the string literal in your snippet, "/d/manhua/naruto/516/1.png|..."

Get rid of the square brackets. "." matches any character just as it is, without brackets. Square brackets are for matching a limited set of characters: For example, you'd use "[abc]" to match any "a", "b", or "c".

It looks like the brackets have the effect of escaping the ".", a feature I hadn't known about (or forgot, sometime in the Ordovician). But I tested the regex as you have it with the string value replaced with a series of dots, and the regex matched. It's being treated as a literal "." character, which you would more likely try to match with a backslash escape: "\."

So just get rid of the brackets and it should work. It works in VS2008 for me.